# Dynamic Tableview inside UItableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, dynamic

I want to implement subTableView with `dynamic height` inside the `UITableViewCell`, where as the subTableView has cells with dynamic `UITableViewCell`.Please share your thoughts on this if anybody have implemented this scenario.

```
-UItableview(Parent)
  -UItableviewCell
     -UITableView(child)
        -UItableviewCell(dynamic content).
```

Answer (score 14):

**First Approach:**  Create a subclass for child tableView and override intrinsicContentSize.

```
         class MyOwnTableView: UITableView {
        override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
            return self.contentSize
        }

        override var contentSize: CGSize {
            didSet{
                self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
            }
        }

        override func reloadData() {
            super.reloadData()
            self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }
```

2.  In Interface builder change the class of your child tableView to MyOwnTableView (subclass UItableView).

3. Set automatic row height for both the parent and child table view.

   ```
       tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60.0;
       tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
   ```

**Second Approach:**
       1. Create a height constraint with any value for child tableView and conect an IBOutlet that sets the child tableView height.
2. Set the height constraint's constant to tableView.contentSize.height

```
    self.tableViewHeight.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height
```

Comment: Where is the best place to put the code for the second approach? `awakeFromNib()` or `layoutSubviews()` or somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks @Leamer you made my day easy ... once again thanks for first approach. :D

Comment: Thanks! This answer solves my problem exactly, which I spent days to figure out the solution.

Comment: Wow. First approach worked! In objectiveC I had to tweak this one a bit
- (void)setContentSize:(CGSize)contentSize
{
    [super setContentSize:contentSize];
    [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
}

Comment: First approach worked! Thanks @Learner

Comment: First and second both approach working but after scrolling.
Any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use Auto Layout when creating your UItableviewCell(dynamic content)..
2. Set the UITableView(child) rowHeight to UITableViewAutomaticDimension.
3. Set the estimatedRowHeight of UITableView(child).

you can see this website:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells

Comment: Hi Hsiao Ai Lee thanks for your answer but i want child tableview to grow according to number of cells. The above logic only make cell dynamic but not the tableview.